# Как получить ссылку на функцию?

Tags: java, android

Есть класс Buttons в котором описываются действия при нажатии на кнопку, и есть класс Button который уже обрабатывает нажатие, рисует кнопку и тп. На питоне это реализуется так:

```
But[0].funct = but_0 #but_0 - функция в которой описаны действия которые должны быть выполнены

for elem in But:
    elem.funct()
```

Необходимо создать что-то похожее на java. Писать n ифов мне не очень хочется.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Получить ссылку на функцию нельзя.

Но можно передать объект который реализует интерфейс (Паттерн [Команда](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29)).

Пример:

```
interface MyWorker {
  doSomething();
}

MyWorker w1 = new MyWorker() {
  doSomething() {
    // w1
  }
}

MyWorker w2 = new MyWorker() {
  doSomething() {
    // w2
  }
}

someMethod(w1);
someMethod(w2);
```

И someMethod() в который мы передаем объект:

```
public void someMethod(MyWorker worker) {
  worker.doSomething();
  // ....
}
```

- То же самое, но при помощи лямбд и Functional Interfaces из Java 8. Для Android на данный момент это неприменимо, там Java 8 не поддерживается.
- При помощи Reflections API

Например, вызовем метод `execute` без параметров класса `DoSthCommand`:

```
Class clazz = DoSthCommand.class;
Method doSth = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("execute", {});
doSth.invoke(clazz.newInstance(), null);
```

Крайне не рекомендуется к применению в повседневной практике ввиду низкой производительности и надругательства над самой сутью ООП в Java.

*В ответе используется часть ответа @fori1ton

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю как это можно использовать в моём случае, у меня все кнопки в массиве.

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю что вы хотите сделать. Вы можете сделать массив обьектов `MyWorker ` из моего примера и у каждого вызвать `doSomething()` в цикле.

Comment: И да, в случае андроида, класс который рисует кнопку называется Button, а действия при нажатии на кнопку - вложенный в Button OnClickListener, я так понимаю у вас кастомная реализация, но советую придерживаться аналогичной терминологии чтобы измежать путаницы.

Answer (score 1):

[Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517153/variable-functions-in-java) есть ответ. Если перевести, то так:

В Java есть `Method` и [`MethodHandle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html), которые могут вызывать методы через Reflection, но это не реализовано в языке

В Java 8 можно использовать ссылки на методы (в Java не бывает функций если придираться к терминологии)

В вашем случае стоит использовать механизм интерфейсов.